# How to make a child div wider than its parent div without covering the surrounding elements

Tags: html, css, parent-child

I have a **parent div** which is basically a very long blog with text and images. I want a **div** inside it to be **wider** as the **parent**, however I don´t want it to cover the surrounding elements. Currently if I do the following it covers the h3 element below it :

```
.parent{
position: relative;
max-width: 800px;

}

.child{
position: absolute;
left:-17rem
}
```

Comment: Please add the HTML code as well

Answer (score 0):

Once you add `position: absolute` you remove it from the document flow, and the rest of the document is rendered *as if it doesn't exist* - meaning that if it's 20px tall, the content below it will move up 20px to fill that space, since they treat it as if it's not there at all.

The initial `overflow` value for Box, Grid, and Flex containers is set to `visible` - so you can position child elements outside of parent elements easily.

Consider using [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and `translateX()`:

```css
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.child {
  width: calc( 100% + 40px ); /* If you want div 40px larger */
  transform: translateX(-20px); /* Offset by half of that value (20px) */
}

/* Just Here for Styling Purposes */
.parent{padding:20px 0;margin:0 auto;background:#09e;}.child{background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);color:#fff;padding:10px 0;text-align:center;}.next {background:#eee;padding:20px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">TEXT IN HERE</div>
</div>
<div class="next">This should remain where it was originally</div>
```